# Error with fetchmail and SSL certificates

Tags: osx, ssl, fetchmail

I have a problem configuring my mail client on my Mac OS 10.6.8. These were the steps I did:

```
# touch ~/.fetchmailrc
```

I edited the file and created the contents:

```
poll pop.gmail.com with proto POP3 and options no dns
user 'GMAIL_USERNAME@gmail.com' there with password 'GMAIL_PASSWORD' is 'LOCAL_USERNAME'            
here and wants mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"  options ssl keep sslcertck sslcertpath 
"/Users/LOCAL_USERNAME/.ssl/certs"
```

Then I executed:

```
# chmod 710 ~/.fetchmailrc
```

I copied the certificates from here http://af-design.com/blog/2010/04/28/using-linux-fetchmail-with-gmail/ into the directory `~/.ssl/certs/` and issued the following commands:

```
# ls ~/.ssl/certs/

    equifax.pem    gmail.pem   imap.gmail.pem

# c_rehash ~/.ssl/certs/
```

This generated the following files in the `~/.ssl/certs` directory:

```
17974aab.0     578d5c04.0     b627f838.0     equifax.pem    gmail.pem      
imap.gmail.pem
```

It seems that I have the correct one as I didn't receive any complaints.
Finally I ran the command:

```
# fetchmail -v
```

and got the error:

```
fetchmail: 6.3.11 querying pop.gmail.com (protocol POP3) at Thu, 03 May 2012 16:41:02    +0200 (CEST): poll started
Trying to connect to 173.194.67.108/995...connected.
fetchmail: Server certificate verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
fetchmail: Certificate/fingerprint verification was somehow skipped!
fetchmail: SSL connection failed.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from lgu.tbz@gmail.com@pop.gmail.com
fetchmail: 6.3.11 querying pop.gmail.com (protocol POP3) at Thu, 03 May 2012 16:41:02 +0200 (CEST): poll completed
fetchmail: Query status=2 (SOCKET)
fetchmail: normal termination, status 2
```

I tried to do as suggested in some forums, for example modifying the username or similar, but it did not help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

according to [this](http://download.gna.org/hpr/fetchmail/FAQ/gmail-pop-howto.html) you shold go to your `~/.ssl/certs` and:

```
wget -O Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem  https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.cer
```

then you have to run following line:

```
  c_rehash ~/.ssl/certs
```

then  `fechmail -v` should not *give Server certificate verification error*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't use this method any more but should some user find it right and helpful it would be nice. Thanks for your answer!!!